# Unix UIDs vs Windows SIDs - why?

Tags: windows, security, unix, acl

From what I've read UIDs in Unix are assigned by the administrator while the SIDs are random in Windows. Is there a security reason behind this, or is it just different ways to solve IDs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UUIDs and SIDs are essentially the same thing.
They're a combination of a system specific part and a timestamp, generated according to a specific algorithm (which might be different between implementations, but that's irrelevant).

Essentially they're both semi-random. Maybe some Unix admins are convinced there's some "security" reason for not handing them out or whatever, but that's nonsense.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. The author is asking about User IDs on Unix, which are (or can be) assigned manually, versus SIDs on Windows, which are partially random but still don't have anything to do with GUIDs/UUIDs.

Comment: Yeah I was wondering if there is a security reason why Windows SIDs are random while UIDs are not. My intuition says no, but I am not very experienced in unix so I don't know for sure

Answer (score 2):

While you may edit /etc/passwd (and /etc/shadow) by hand on a Unix machine, the standard way to add users is through a `useradd` utility (or similar) which should automatically assign the next available UID. So they should be assigned automatically rather than by the administrator. SIDs are more complicated (i.e. hierarchical) so assigning them by hand would be even more cumbersome (and besides, you cannot update the SAM database by hand anyway).

As to assigning them randomly, the SID's random part is the Machine SID, which gives SID the advantage of being unambiguous (as opposed to Unix UIDs). For example, if MACHINE1 has local user ALICE and an NTFS volume with some files owned by MACHINE1\ALICE, when you plug this volume into MACHINE2, it won't make a mistake of thinking those files are owned by some local MACHINE2 user which just happens to have the same SID (whether named ALICE or otherwise).

On Unix, if alice had UID 501 on MACHINE1, then then you plug the same volume into MACHINE2 where UID 501 belongs to bob, ls will show the files as belonging to bob (rather than to alice or even to an 'unknown UID').

Answer (score 0):

The windows SID is a GLOBALLY Unique Identifier vs the Unix UID which is not globally unique.